# How do I set up an automated CSV export job from Azure SQL Server?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-automation

In an on-prem SQL Server I have the option to set up scheduled Jobs with the SQL Server Agent. This feature is not present in Azure. Is there any way to do this easily in Azure or will I have to rely on automation scripts  / powershell scripting for this?

The task I want to accomplish is to export a bunch of SQL views to CSV and send them to a remote FTP server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Azure, through **Logic Apps**, you can achieve this. Please check below steps.

1. Go to **Azure Portal** ( http://portal.azure.com/ ) and Search **Logic Apps**.
2. Click **Add** and fill the details like **Logic App Name**, **Subscription**,**Resource group**, **Location** and click **Create**.
3. After refreshing the page, click the Created Logic App. In the home page, choose **Blank Logic App**.
4. In the Logic Apps designer Page, Search for **Schedule** or **Recurrence** and click it.
5. Fill the **Interval, Frequency, Time zone (Format is important – 2018-10-16T21:00:00Z ), Start time, at these hours, at these minutes**, Check the Preview.
6. **Choose an Action**, Search for **SQL Server** and Click **Execute Stored Procedure** in the list.
7. Click **Add New connection** at the end if you want to create new connection. Then **Click Manually Enter Connection Information** at the end if you want to create new connection.
8. Or else use anyone of the Existing connections. Fill the **Procedure name** with the required SP & below are the input parameters of the SP that you selected.
9. **Choose an Action**, Search for **Create CSV Table** and Click it. Fill the From (choose dynamic result set from the right side-Choose first result set alone), Include Headers (Yes), Columns (Automatic).
10. **Choose an Action**, Search for **Office 365 Outlook** & Search for **Send an Email** and Click it. Before proceeding, Please check mail id at the bottom. Change as yours. Fill the To (zzzzzz@xxxxxx.com;zzzzz@xxxxx.com), Subject (Demo mail), Body (Please check the test attachment), From & CC & BCC (email id’s for whom you want to send), Important (Normal), Is HTML (NO), Attachment Name {choose expression from the right hand side and type **concat('Test_mail',utcnow('dd-MM-yyyy'),'.csv')**  }, Attachment Content (Choose **output** from the right hand side).
11. Finally Click **Save** at the left hand side top. Click **Designer** option to edit, after edit completes, again save that. Click **Run** for Demo Run.
    Click **Run** to initiate the trigger. Then only the automated mails should come at mentioned intervals.
    Select the Required Logic App and click **Delete** to delete it (will ask Logic App name to delete).
    You should have access to do the above changes and you have to sign in to open the azure portal.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use Azure Data Factory and create a copy activity that use [Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database) as a source and [SFTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sftp) as a sink.  Use [copy activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview) to copy data from any supported data store to your SFTP server located on-premises or in the cloud. You can schedule execution on Azure Data Factory as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-scheduling-and-execution).

Another option is using Azure Logic Apps with the [Azure SQL Database connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-sqlazure) and [FTP connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-ftp) to access/manage SQL Database and FTP server. You can create, schedule, and run recurring tasks with Azure Logic Apps as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-recurrence).